# Verify TortoiseGit-2.8.0.0-64bit.msi with gpg2

Tags: gnupg, tortoisegit, pgp, verify

I want to download and verify TortoiseGit-2.8.0.0-64bit.msi

I use gnupg2 (in Cygwin)

The TortoiseGit [download page](https://download.tortoisegit.org/tgit/2.8.0.0/) provides these files:

```
TortoiseGit-2.8.0.0-64bit.msi
TortoiseGit-2.8.0.0-64bit.msi.rsa.asc
```

I did the below to verify a download (but got: No public key):

```
$ gpg2 --auto-key-locate keyserver --keyserver-options auto-key-retrieve -- 
verify TortoiseGit-2.8.0.0-64bit.msi.rsa.asc TortoiseGit-2.8.0.0-64bit.msi
gpg: Signature made Thu, Feb 28, 2019  4:34:13 PM EST
gpg:                using RSA key 74A21AE301B3CA5BD8072F5EF7F17B3F9DD9539E
gpg: requesting key F7F17B3F9DD9539E from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

Since I don't have a .sig I tried and got:

```
$ gpg2 --import TortoiseGit-2.8.0.0-64bit.msi.rsa.asc
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I can't understand how then to properly verify this download -- if anyone can show the correct method it would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: The key is available here: https://download.tortoisegit.org/keys/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is available here: https://download.tortoisegit.org/keys.

As the MSI files are also signed using AuthentiCode, there is no real need for the GPG signatures for end users. - The GPG signatures are used by the auto-updater in order to verify the integrity of the update packages (despite the fact that those are also downloaded using HTTPs).

If you need another trust root, you can call `TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:pgpfp` in order to display the GPG fingerprint.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, how to verify this GPG signature.

Comment: As basically written in the question: Import the public key to your gnupg keyring (e.g., `gpg --import F7F17B3F9DD9539E.asc`) and then `gpg --verify TortoiseGit-2.8.0.0-64bit.msi.rsa.asc TortoiseGit-2.8.0.0-64bit.msi`, you might need to sign the public key and set the trust level before